# Struts 1.x to Struts 2.x Migration issues for Scriptlet in s:textarea field

Tags: struts2

I am working on Struts 1.x to Struts 2.x migration and facing issues while assigning Scriptlet in textarea value.

**The following code was written in Struts 1.x below :**

```
<html:textarea  name="shareFeedbackForm" style="height:50px;"
                                property="checkAllRemarks(${shrFeedbackHelperForm.groupId})" rows="1" cols="20" 
value = '<%=(String)checkedMap.get(Long.parseLong((String)session.getAttribute("gId")))  %>' styleId="${shrFeedbackHelperForm.groupId}" onkeydown="limitRemarksText(this,500);" onkeyup="limitRemarksText(this,500);"></html:textarea>
```

**I tried to re-write the same in Struts 2.x expression :**

```
 <s:textarea  style="height:50px;" 
name="webform.checkAllRemarks(%{#attr.shrFeedbackHelperForm.groupId})" rows="1" cols="20" value = '<%=(String)checkedMap.get(Long.parseLong((String)session.getAttribute("gId")))  %>' id="%{#attr.shrFeedbackHelperForm.groupId}" onkeydown="limitRemarksText(this,500);" onkeyup="limitRemarksText(this,500);"></s:textarea>
```

But, I am getting error in page where attribute **value** does not  allow expressions. What is the correct way to assign the scriptlet in JSP page for Struts 2.x framework?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

**You Can Add Scriptlet in STRUTS 2 as follows**

```
<%
String str=request.getAttribute("tDate").toString();
%>

<s:textfield value=<%=str %> name="toDate" id="toDate" />
```

**Please try the following code**

```
<s:textarea  style="height:50px;" 
name="webform.checkAllRemarks(%{#attr.shrFeedbackHelperForm.groupId})" 
rows="1" cols="20" value = '<%=checkedMap.get(Long.parseLong(session.getAttribute("gId"))).toString()  %>' id="%{#attr.shrFeedbackHelperForm.groupId}" 
onkeydown="limitRemarksText(this,500);" onkeyup="limitRemarksText(this,500);"></s:textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks Pawan. I am getting the same issue after adding the value expression  like : value = '<%=checkedMap.get(Long.parseLong(session.getAttribute("gId").toString()))  %>'

Comment: why you are doing Long.parseLong() over here?

Comment: Because the checkedMap is Map Data type with Key as Long and Value as String.

Comment: check out my edited code

Comment: I tried this below code  and I think it shld work:                            
 <%
               String variable = (String)checkedMap.get(Long.parseLong((String)session.getAttribute("gId")));
              %>

              <s:textarea  style="height:50px;"
                  name="webform.checkAllRemarks(%{#attr.shrFeedbackHelperForm.groupId})" rows="1" cols="20"
                  value = "%{#variable}" id="%{#attr.shrFeedbackHelperForm.groupId}" onkeydown="limitRemarksText(this,500);" onkeyup="limitRemarksText(this,500);"></s:textarea>

Comment: is above code is working?

Comment: Yes, I will check and post back to you.

Comment: please mark as useful and give vote to answer